# TcpDump: showing the absolute timestamp (date + time) of pcap file

Tags: timestamp, pcap, tcpdump

I want to see the absolute timestamp of the packets in a pcap file using tcpdump. When I use the command `tcpdump -r mypcapfiile` it only shows the time,

```
03:21:14.804778 IP static.vnpt.vn.51193 > 192.168.0.146.smtp
```

how can read the date as well?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `-tttt` option:

```
$ tcpdump -tttt -nr tmp.pcap 
reading from file tmp.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
2018-01-19 17:50:43.275918 IP 172.24.0.97.45386 > 93.153.221.29.80: Flags [.], ack 3335572340, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 98777655 ecr 230462279], length 0
2018-01-19 17:50:43.287273 IP 93.153.221.29.80 > 172.24.0.97.45386: Flags [.], ack 1, win 285, options [nop,nop,TS val 230464839 ecr 98706059], length 0
2018-01-19 17:50:44.138480 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.73 tell 172.24.0.78, length 46
2018-01-19 17:50:45.162482 ARP, Request who-has 172.24.0.73 tell 172.24.0.78, length 46
```

Comment: When you do this, be sure to set the TZ environment variable appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Below example will give output of timestamp

`tcpdump -i any -lnv port 53 -tttt | egrep -i "something" -B1`

Example:
`2021-01-29 00:17:28.143766 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 254, id 60132, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 68) 10.10.15.4.9193 > 10.10.27.251.53: 42463+ A? something.com. (40)`